# How to programmatically change region for field instance?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have content type with more then one regions. When I open admin page "Manage fields" I can see which fields are in which regions. Is it possible to change programatically, in which region some field instance should be? (I don't need to create new region, just switch field to another existing region)

Comment: What do you mean by regions here? I have flat field list under  Administration > Structure > Content types > Basic Page > Manage fields. No regions there. Probably you installed something, but you are not talking about regions in the meaning of [tag:regions] tag, apparently.

Comment: Any chance you mean "group" as in those provided by the field group module?

Comment: After doing research, I found that it is done with Display suites https://www.drupal.org/node/1795354